# AWS Amplify Image Upload Issue: Body must be a string error

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, expo, aws-amplify

I am encountering a problem with image uploads using AWS Amplify in my React Native application. I am using the Storage module to upload images to an S3 bucket, but I consistently receive the following error:
Error picking image: [Error: Body must be a string. Received: undefined.]

Issue Context:

I'm using AWS Amplify in a React Native project for image uploads.
The image selection is done through an image picker, and the selected image URI is then used to fetch the image and upload it to an S3 bucket.
Code Snippet:

I've provided the component below:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Image } from "react-native";
import { Auth, API, graphqlOperation, Storage } from "aws-amplify";
import { GetKidByParentEmail } from "../../graphql/queries";
import { UpdateKid } from "../../graphql/mutations";
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";
import * as FileSystem from "expo-file-system";

import styles from "./styles";

const PickScreen = () => {
  const [kid, setKid] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchKidData = async () => {
      try {
        const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
        const userEmail = user.attributes.email;

        const kidData = await API.graphql(
          graphqlOperation(GetKidByParentEmail, {
            userEmail: userEmail,
          })
        );

        const kids = kidData.data.listKids.items;
        setKid(kids);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching Kid data:", error);
      }
    };

    fetchKidData();
  }, []);

  const uploadImage = async (uri, kidID) => {
    try {
      if (!uri) {
        throw new Error("Image URI is undefined");
      }

      console.log("Fetching image from:", uri);
      const response = await fetch(uri);
      const blob = await response.blob();

      console.log("Uploading image to S3...");
      const filename = `kid-photo-${kidID}-${Date.now()}`;
      await Storage.put(filename, blob, {
        contentType: "image/jpeg",
      });

      console.log("Image uploaded successfully.");

      const imageURL = await Storage.get(filename);
      console.log("Image URL:", imageURL);

      return imageURL;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error uploading image:", error);
      throw error;
    }
  };

  const openImageLibrary = async () => {
    try {
      const permissionResult =
        await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();

      if (permissionResult.granted === false) {
        console.log("Permission to access camera roll is required!");
        return;
      }

      const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
        allowsEditing: true,
        aspect: [4, 3],
        quality: 1,
      });
      console.log("ImagePicker Result:", result);

      if (!result.cancelled) {
        if (result.assets && result.assets.length > 0) {
          const imageURL = await uploadImage(result.assets[0].uri, kid[0].id);

          console.log("Selected Image:", imageURL);

          // Update the kid's photo in the state
          setKid((prevKids) => {
            const updatedKids = prevKids.map((kidItem) => {
              if (kidItem.id === kid[0].id) {
                return {
                  ...kidItem,
                  photo: imageURL,
                };
              } else {
                return kidItem;
              }
            });

            return updatedKids;
          });

          // Update the kid's photo in the GraphQL API
          await API.graphql(
            graphqlOperation(UpdateKid, {
              input: {
                id: kid[0].id,
                photo: imageURL,
              },
            })
          );
        } else {
          console.error("Image assets not found in the result.");
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error picking image:", error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View>
      {kid ? (
        <View>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, fontWeight: "bold" }}>Kid Details</Text>
          {kid.map((kidItem) => (
            <View key={kidItem.id}>
              <Text>Name: {kidItem.name}</Text>
              <Text>Drop-off Address: {kidItem.dropOffAddress}</Text>
              {kidItem.photo && (
                <Image
                  style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}
                  source={{ uri: kidItem.photo }}
                />
              )}
            </View>
          ))}
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={openImageLibrary}>
            <View style={styles.button}>
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Open Image Library</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      ) : (
        <Text>Loading...</Text>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default PickScreen;
```

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

I have already updated my code based on community suggestions, including addressing the deprecated key warnings and ensuring that the URI is not undefined.
Additional Information:

The issue persists even after the code modifications.
AWS Amplify and dependencies are updated to the latest versions.
I am seeking guidance on identifying the root cause of the "Body must be a string" error during image uploads using AWS Amplify. Any insights, suggestions, or debugging tips would be greatly appreciated.